# flutter webview navigation menu is not working

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, navigation

I'm trying to make a webview app for my website and use the following starter code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter1',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter1'),
        ),
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: "URL.com",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**PROBLEM**
While the app opens the page, the navigation menu (three dots) do not respond when I click.

[image]

What can I do?

**EDIT**
I also tried to ***allow all mixed content*** using `flutter_inappwebview`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter2',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter2'),
        ),
        body: InAppWebView(
          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("www.URL.com")),
          initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                  mixedContentMode: AndroidMixedContentMode.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE
              )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Still the dots are not working.

Comment: Where is the code for the navigation menu? What do you see in the logs/chrome inspect?

Comment: @tomerpacific actually logs do not show that anything is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to have a controller for your Navigation- and WebView-Menu

```
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
  Completer<WebViewController>();
```

then in your build methode:

```
    Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Webview'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              NavigationControls(_controller.future),
              WebViewMenu(_controller.future),
            ],
    }
      ),
 body: Builder(....)...
```

these are the classes from https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example

```
class WebViewMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  WebViewMenu(this.controller);

  final Future<WebViewController> controller;
  final CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: controller,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
        if (controller.hasError) {
          return Text('Controller has Error');
        }
        return PopupMenuButton<MenuOptions>(
          onSelected: (MenuOptions value) {
            switch (value) {
              case MenuOptions.showUserAgent:
                _onShowUserAgent(controller.data!, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.listCookies:
                _onListCookies(controller.data!, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.clearCookies:
                _onClearCookies(context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.addToCache:
                _onAddToCache(controller.data!, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.listCache:
                _onListCache(controller.data!, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.clearCache:
                _onClearCache(controller.data!, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.navigationDelegate:
                _onNavigationDelegateExample(controller.data!, context);
                break;
            }
          },
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>>[
            PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.showUserAgent,
              child: const Text('Show user agent'),
              enabled: controller.hasData,
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.listCookies,
              child: Text('List cookies'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.clearCookies,
              child: Text('Clear cookies'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.addToCache,
              child: Text('Add to cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.listCache,
              child: Text('List cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.clearCache,
              child: Text('Clear cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.navigationDelegate,
              child: Text('Navigation Delegate example'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _onShowUserAgent(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    // Send a message with the user agent string to the Toaster JavaScript channel we registered
    // with the WebView.
    await controller.evaluateJavascript(
        'Toaster.postMessage("User Agent: " + navigator.userAgent);');
  }

  void _onListCookies(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final String cookies =
        await controller.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie');
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('Cookies:'),
          _getCookieList(cookies),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  void _onAddToCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.evaluateJavascript(
        'caches.open("test_caches_entry"); localStorage["test_localStorage"] = "dummy_entry";');
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Added a test entry to cache.'),
    ));
  }

  void _onListCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.evaluateJavascript('caches.keys()'
        '.then((cacheKeys) => JSON.stringify({"cacheKeys" : cacheKeys, "localStorage" : localStorage}))'
        '.then((caches) => Toaster.postMessage(caches))');
  }

  void _onClearCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.clearCache();
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text("Cache cleared."),
    ));
  }

  void _onClearCookies(BuildContext context) async {
    final bool hadCookies = await cookieManager.clearCookies();
    String message = 'There were cookies. Now, they are gone!';
    if (!hadCookies) {
      message = 'There are no cookies.';
    }
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
    ));
  }

  void _onNavigationDelegateExample(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final String contentBase64 =
        base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(kNavigationExamplePage));
    await controller.loadUrl('data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64');
  }

  Widget _getCookieList(String cookies) {
    if (cookies == null || cookies == '""') {
      return Container();
    }
    final List<String> cookieList = cookies.split(';');
    final Iterable<Text> cookieWidgets =
        cookieList.map((String cookie) => Text(cookie));
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: cookieWidgets.toList(),
    );
  }
}

class NavigationControls extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationControls(this._webViewControllerFuture);

  final Future<WebViewController> _webViewControllerFuture;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: _webViewControllerFuture,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final bool webViewReady =
              snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done;
          final WebViewController controller = snapshot.data!;
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                onPressed: !webViewReady
                    ? null
                    : () async {
                        if (await controller.canGoBack()) {
                          await controller.goBack();
                        } else {
                          // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(
                                content: Text("No back history item")),
                          );
                          return;
                        }
                      },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                onPressed: !webViewReady
                    ? null
                    : () async {
                        if (await controller.canGoForward()) {
                          await controller.goForward();
                        } else {
                          // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(
                                content: Text("No forward history item")),
                          );
                          return;
                        }
                      },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.replay),
                onPressed: !webViewReady
                    ? null
                    : () {
                        controller.reload();
                      },
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
        return Text('loading navigationControls');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I used the example from the link you gave, and unfortunately the "dots" still do not respond :(