# WebView and bottom navigation bar don't work in sync in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

```
`WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://github.com/'));


  WebViewController second = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://github.com/pricing'));`

` int selectedIndex = 0;

    void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  setState(() {
    selectedIndex = index;
  });
}



static  final List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
  WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
  WebViewWidget(controller: second),
];`

`Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,15,15,15),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: '',
          ),
            ],
            currentIndex: selectedIndex, 
          onTap: _onItemTapped,    
            
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: 
      Center(
    child: _pages.elementAt(selectedIndex), 
  ),
    );`
```

I have a navigation bar as seen above and I want to use the webview_flutter package when these options are clicked. There is no problem for the first page. When I click the Home icon it brings me the homepage of github. But when I click on the second icon in the navigationbar, it still brings up the github homepage. But I am trying to reach the github/pricing page.

Comment: You can certainly find a solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69143574/flutter-webview-navigation-menu-is-not-working